# jQuery navigation-items with nested submenus should open on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to add a second level of submenus here.

Is there a dynamic solution, so only one submenu is opened, when clicking on the link?
And when clicking a link to a submenu (in the first submenu), then open this one?
And so on…

I already changed the jsfiddle a little, to have one level of sublevels more: http://jsfiddle.net/cRsZE/363/

Working example with one level of submenus: [**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cRsZE/)

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li class="parent">About
        <ul class="sub-nav">
            <li>Johnny</li>
            <li>Julie</li>
            <li>Jamie</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
#nav ul.sub-nav {
    display: none;
}

#nav ul.visible {
    display: block;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.parent').click(function() {
        $('.sub-nav').toggleClass('visible');
    });
});
```

Source: [Creating Drop Down Menu on click CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786546/creating-drop-down-menu-on-click-css/18787019#18787019)

Answer (score 0):

Try,

CSS:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('ul ul').addClass('hidden');

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.parent').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).find('ul').first().toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cRsZE/365/)

Comment: Thanks for this! The example works, but I cannot use it this way in my project. Is there a way without adding a class in the beginning before anything happens?

Comment: @mandar1ne let me know if the given solution works for you.. :)

Comment: "visible" isn't used anywhere, or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: @mandar1ne That is unnecessary basically. Is that working in your website.?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. At first it works but then it kinda refreshes and is like it was before (so, then menu is "closed" again).