# dropdown menu on click with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I've been working with [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786546/creating-drop-down-menu-on-click-css#answer-18787019). But I don't have the rep to ask them the question.

I have this setup in a Wordpress install using the default menu hierarchy that Wordpress spits out, like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu-featured-categories-container">
<ul id="menu-featured-categories">
    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
      <a href="#">Featured Categories</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#menu-featured-categories ul.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}

#menu-featured-categories ul.visible {
    display: block;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-item-has-children').click(function() {
        $('.sub-menu').toggleClass('visible');
    });
});
```

It's just not working for me. So my question is: What am I doing wrong? Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just a thought - have you tried using `.on('click', function() { ... });` instead? I know `.click()` can have issues with dynamically inserted elements, although that may not be the issue you're seeing.

Comment: Your code work fiine see the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0x5xssk/43/)**.

Comment: Thanks. Mohammed Alsaedi answer worked. Apparently has something to do with how Wordpress processes jQuery. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many cases, you need to use noConflict mode to write your jQuery in Wordpress. Alternatively, you can use 'jQuery' instead of $ in all instances.

So here are your options, either replace the wrapping

```
$(document).ready(function(){
});
```

with

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
```

Your second option is to rewrite your code as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.menu-item-has-children').click(function() {
        jQuery('.sub-menu').toggleClass('visible');
    });
});
```

Either of these should resolve your issue, considering that the code works, which it seemingly does based on Zakaria's [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0x5xssk/43/) in the comments.

Cheers!

Comment: Amazing. Worked perfectly. Thank you.