# Changing WordPress mainnav :hover to click

Tags: css, wordpress

I am an amateur developer looking to develop my skills in the world of programming. I apologize for any redundancy that may occur in the stackoverflow forum, but I felt that personalized assistance would solve my question quite a bit faster.

My current site has the main navigation menu set to hover only, if you were to move the cursor off of the menu it disappears. I would like this to be a click-menu. I am not sure what to do, this may be an easy fix but I would feel more comfortable getting the help of a grizzly veteran.

(I have little/no JavaScript Experience)

I believe this is where my problem may lie, but I am hesitant to alter my theme's css.

## mainnav-menu li:hover ul ul, #mainnav-menu li:hover ul ul ul, #mainnav-menu li:hover ul ul ul ul{

```
display:none;
```

}

## mainnav-menu li:hover ul, #mainnav-menu li li:hover ul, #mainnav-menu li li li:hover ul, #mainnav-menu li li li li:hover ul{

```
display:block;
```

P.S. I am new to the web development community so I have been very hesitant to ask for help / stick my neck out. I would truly appreciate any support.

Andrew

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Drop Down Menu on click CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786546/creating-drop-down-menu-on-click-css)

Comment: Hi Andrew. Couple of things, please see the link in my comment above for some ways of achieving the functionality you are after. Also, be aware that you really need to include all the relevant code in your question (HTML, CSS and JavaScript) to help us be able to replicate and assist you with your issue.