# What's the best method to toggle a login form window in a div when a user clicks a button using CSS only?

Tags: html, css, forms, button

In my website, I have a button that I want users to be able to use to toggle a Login window when it's clicked.  What's the best way to go about it using CSS only?  I only know of the ':hover' trick but I don't know if there is anything for a 'user button click'.

The form should not disappear when users click anywhere within its area but should disappear when they click anywhere else outside the area.  I'm also planning to put an 'X' close button on the top-right using an image file so when users click on it, the login form closes.

How may I go about it using CSS only?

```css
#loginWindow{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px red solid;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
}

.loginForm {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="toggle">Toggle Log In Window</button>

<div id="loginWindow">
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="login" class="loginForm" placeholder="Enter username"><br>
    <input type="password" id="password" class="loginForm" placeholder="Enter password"><br>
    <button type="submit" id="login" class="loginForm">Log In</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Check the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786546/creating-drop-down-menu-on-click-css

Comment: Those answers use jQuery.  Is it not possible to do with only CSS?

Comment: Some of them use jquery, some not. did you manage to go over all the answers there?

Answer (score 0):

### You will not be able to achieve this using CSS only.

CSS is for **style** not for **interactivity**. If you want interactive response towards your user, then *javascript* is your way to go, why do you try to avoid it?

This is achievable with only a few js lines.

```js
var toggle=true,
    loginwindow = document.getElementById('loginWindow');
```

```css
            #loginWindow{
                height: 200px;
                width: 200px;
                border: 1px red solid;
                background-color: red;
                padding: 20px;
            }
            .loginForm {
                margin: 10px;
                padding: 5px;
            }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <body>
        <button type="button" id="toggle" onclick="toggle=!toggle;loginwindow.style.display = toggle?'block':'none'">Toggle Log In Window</button>
    <div id="loginWindow">
        <form>
        <input type="text" id="login" class="loginForm" placeholder="Enter username"><br>
        <input type="password" id="password" class="loginForm" placeholder="Enter password"><br>
        <button type="submit" id="login" class="loginForm">Log In</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```